# What permissions does db_owner not have? (In SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can you list the permissions that db_owner cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

[Permissions of Fixed Database Roles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189612(v=sql.100).aspx): `db_owner`: has `CONTROL` permission with GRANT option in the database and `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission in the server. To understand what that entails, read all of the following:

- [Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191291(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [Principals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181127(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [Securables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190401(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [Permission Hierarchy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465(v=sql.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also drop the database.

For Ref : - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From [books online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx), members of the db_owner fixed database role can: -

> Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all
>   configuration and maintenance activities on the database, and can also
>   drop the database.

Those permissions are specific to an individual database. What that login doesn't have, is permissions in other databases (unless granted separately) or server level permissions.

Server level permissions would be granted by adding the login to a [server level role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx) or by granting specific [server level permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Any members of the db_owner fixed server role can do anything they want within that database (include drop the database).  They can't do anything outside the database without additional rights.